# How to select vertical coloumn to horizontal coloumn?

Tags: shell, awk

i have a file txt which has data as below:

```
k1|k2|k3
1|65|98
2|42|55
3|21|56
4|76|89
5|34|93
6|78|22
```

and i want to transform the data like this:

```
k1|1|2|3|4|5|6
k2|65|42|21|76|34|78
k3|98|55|56|89|93|22
```

Any help can give me good lesson. Btw im new in coding and i want to learn shell script.
Thank You

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts in their posts, so kindly do edit your question with same and let us know then.

Answer (score 1):

Using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) makes it trivial:

```
$ datamash -t'|' transpose < input.txt
k1|1|2|3|4|5|6
k2|65|42|21|76|34|78
k3|98|55|56|89|93|22
```